# Identifying files which are not currently written

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to transfer some log files from one folder to another in Ubuntu operating system.

My question is how do I understand that a log file is written and no more writing is done on that?

Is there any command which would help identifying that?

Actually I want to do that through a shell script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [lsof](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_lsof.htm) command can help you identify if any process is using a certain file.

For a simple example, I have created a test file in my home folder, and tailed to it.
This is the output of lsof for that file:

```
hovanessyan@workstation:~$ lsof /home/hovanessyan/test
COMMAND   PID        USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
tail    16858 hovanessyan    3r   REG    8,1      200 43785764 /home/hovanessyan/test
```

You can see the command that's using the file, the pid etc.

Here are some more detailed and complex examples:
[one](http://www.lainoox.com/lsof-list-open-files-linux-unix/) and [two](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-lsof.html)

Comment: actually I want exclude the files which are currently being written. So is there a way I can do that?

Comment: you can check the exit code of lsof. "echo $?" if it's 0 the file is in use, 1 if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

`fuser` - identify processes using files or sockets

Also maybe `inotify` will help.